# How to move jpanel to another jpanel in a same jframe

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a two `JPanel`s: `a1` and `a2`. `a11` is sub panel of `a1`. I want move `a11` to `a2`.
How to do this?

Comment: Should it be on both a1 and a2?

Comment: what do you mean move? dragging? coding?

Comment: what happens if you just append a11 to a2? What have you tried?

Comment: `a11.add(a2)`...adding a component to a container will automatically remove from the it's current parent.  This will cause the containers to be invalidated automatically...

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
a2.add(a11); // move a11 from a1 to a2
a2.revalidate(); // apply changes in a2 layout
a1.revalidate(); // apply changes in a1 layout
a2.repaint(); // repaint a2 you to be able to see the changes
a1.repaint(); // repaint a1 you to be able to see the changes
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do that by first remove a11 from a1 and then adding it to a2.

as follows,

`a1.remove(a11);

a2.add(a11);

a2.repaint();`

Comment: There is no need to remove `a11` from `a1`. The method `a2.add(a11)` will do it for you ;)